# delete a sub-string for all values in a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe :

```
action,adresse_ip,ip_source,ip_dest,client

block,ip="128.30.03.29", source="29E9t9994" ,destination="12300rtgR30" ,client1

block,ip="13.19.04.22",source="29E9th9994" ,destination="12300Rg30" ,client1

allow,ip="40.77.05.293", source="29dfbfE99994", destination="12d300R30" ,client2

block,ip="128.90.73.294", source="29E99fv994" , destination="1230s0R30" ,client2

allow,ip="128.30.83.295", source="29Egfn99994" ,destination="12h300R30",client3

allow,ip="90.03.93.296", source="29E99fv994" ,destination="123k00R30",client5

allow,ip="128.30.04.297", source="29E99994" ,destination="12300tR30" ,client7

block,ip="128.40.01.298", source="29E99994" ,destination="1230z0R30",client8

block,ip="128.50.02.299", source="29E99994" ,destination="1230v0R30" ,client9
```

**I want to delete the last byte for column "adresse_ip", so i want a dataframe like this :**

```
action,adresse_ip,ip_source,ip_dest,client

block,ip="128.30.03", source="29E9t9994" ,destination="12300rtgR30" ,client1

block,ip="13.19.04",source="29E9th9994" ,destination="12300Rg30" ,client1

allow,ip="40.77.05", source="29dfbfE99994", destination="12d300R30" ,client2

block,ip="128.90.73", source="29E99fv994" , destination="1230s0R30" ,client2

allow,ip="128.30.83", source="29Egfn99994" ,destination="12h300R30",client3

allow,ip="90.03.93", source="29E99fv994" ,destination="123k00R30",client5

allow,ip="128.30.04", source="29E99994" ,destination="12300tR30" ,client7

block,ip="128.40.01", source="29E99994" ,destination="1230z0R30",client8

block,ip="128.50.02", source="29E99994" ,destination="1230v0R30" ,client9
```

Please Help,

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please edit your question aiming at a more readable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `replace` method on the `str` accessor with a regex.

```
df['adresse_ip'] = df['adresse_ip'].str.replace('\.\d+"$', '"', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use **apply** function.

```
df['ip_address'] = df['ip_address'].apply(lambda x: '.'.join(x.split('"')[1].split('.')[:3]))
```

Comment: @timgeb Ohh I see. I was thinking that his data is a raw ip address but it ends up containing extra text.  Thank you.